# Refresh a panel when some controls deleted programmaticaly

Tags: vb.net

I am using this part of code to add a **Label**, a **TextBox** a **Button** and a **RadioButton** into a **Panel**:

```
Private Sub AppsAdd_Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AppsAdd_Button.Click
    Dim lbl As New Label()
    Dim count As Integer = Apps_Panel.Controls.OfType(Of Label)().ToList().Count
    lbl.Name = "AppLabel_" & (count + 1)
    lbl.Text = "Application #" & (count + 1) & ":"
    lbl.Location = New Point(0, 28 * count)
    lbl.AutoSize = False
    lbl.Size = New Size(114, 21)
    lbl.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight
    lbl.Tag = count + 1
    Apps_Panel.Controls.Add(lbl)

    Dim txtbox As New TextBox()
    count = Apps_Panel.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().ToList().Count
    txtbox.Name = "AppTextbox_" & (count + 1)
    txtbox.Text = "..."
    txtbox.Location = New Point(120, 28 * count)
    txtbox.Size = New Size(387, 21)
    txtbox.Tag = count + 1
    AddHandler txtbox.TextChanged, AddressOf TextBox_Changed
    Apps_Panel.Controls.Add(txtbox)

    Dim btn As New Button()
    count = Apps_Panel.Controls.OfType(Of Button)().ToList().Count
    btn.Name = "AppBrowseButton_" & (count + 1)
    btn.Text = "Browse"
    btn.Location = New Point(513, 28 * count)
    btn.Size = New Size(75, 21)
    btn.Tag = count + 1
    AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
    Apps_Panel.Controls.Add(btn)

    Dim radiobtn As New RadioButton()
    count = Apps_Panel.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)().ToList().Count
    radiobtn.Name = "AppRadio_" & (count + 1)
    radiobtn.Text = ""
    radiobtn.Location = New Point(590, 28 * count)
    radiobtn.Size = New Size(14, 21)
    radiobtn.Tag = count + 1
    AddHandler radiobtn.Click, AddressOf RadioButton_Click
    Apps_Panel.Controls.Add(radiobtn)
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox_Changed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim textbox As TextBox = TryCast(sender, TextBox)
End Sub
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim button As Button = TryCast(sender, Button)
End Sub
Private Sub RadioButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim RadioButton As RadioButton = TryCast(sender, RadioButton)
    AppToDel_Label.Text = RadioButton.Tag
End Sub
```

Then I use this to remove selected controls:

```
Private Sub AppsDel_Button_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles AppsDel_Button.Click
    Dim Ctrl As Control
    For controlIndex As Integer = Apps_Panel.Controls.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Ctrl = Apps_Panel.Controls(controlIndex)
        If Ctrl.Name Like "*" & AppToDel_Label.Text Then
            RemoveHandler Ctrl.TextChanged, AddressOf TextBox_Changed
            RemoveHandler Ctrl.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
            RemoveHandler Ctrl.Click, AddressOf RadioButton_Click
            Apps_Panel.Controls.Remove(Ctrl)
            Ctrl.Dispose()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

When selected controls are in the bottom of panel, panel is getting smaller in height when I delete them. But if I choose to delete from the top or the middle of panel "list", leaves an empty space and panel don't shrink! Any idea? There is anyway to refresh the panel so it can fill in the empty space?

[Here](https://youtu.be/3yWuMhtQ5Ro) is a video example.

Comment: It would probably be easier to create a user control of those items so you are creating and removing fewer things.  But either way, removing from the middle means you need to iterate and re position the remainder.  A FlowLayoutPanel could manage the position for you

Comment: @Plutonix thank you very much for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead. The `FlowLayoutPanel` layouts the controls added to it automatically. It can arrange items horizontally or vertically.
You don't specify a location when adding them, instead you work with Margins and Paddings.

I also would combine all controls of one row (Label, TextBox, Button and RadioButton) into a [UserControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). This allows you to design the rows visually instead of programmatically.

[Walkthrough: Arranging Controls on Windows Forms Using a FlowLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-arranging-controls-on-windows-forms-using-a-flowlayoutpanel).

[Working with Windows Forms FlowLayoutPanel](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/flowlayoutpanel-in-C-Sharp/) (C# Corner).